# How to import uint16_t array from binary data in Python?

Tags: python, data-conversion

I tried it with numpy:

```
numpy.fromfile(file_name, dtype=numpy.uint16)
```

but I get wrong numbers for example 0x3000 is converted to 48 which should be 12288.

Using struct.unpack didn't work:

```
struct.unpack("i" * ((len(bin_data.tobytes())) // 4), bin_data.tobytes())
```

because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lc3.py", line 386, in <module>
    main()
  File "lc3.py", line 372, in main
    a = struct.unpack("i" * ((len(bin_data.tobytes())) // 4), bin_data.tobytes())
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 32 bytes
```

This is the binary:

```
00000000: 00110000 00000000 11100000 00000010 11110000 00100010  0...."
00000006: 11110000 00100101 00000000 01001000 00000000 01100101  .%.H.e
0000000c: 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101100 00000000 01101111  .l.l.o
00000012: 00000000 00101100 00000000 00100000 00000000 01010111  .,. .W
00000018: 00000000 01101111 00000000 01110010 00000000 01101100  .o.r.l
0000001e: 00000000 01100100 00000000 00000000                    .d..
```

This is the data I want:

```
0x3000,
0xE005,
0x2212,
0xF022,
0x127F,
0x03FD,
0xF025,
0x0048,
0x0065,
0x006C,
0x006C,
0x006F,
0x0020,
0x0057,
0x006F,
0x0072,
0x006C,
0x0064,
0x0021,
0x000A,
0x0000,
0x0005
```

This is the data I get:

```
['0x30', '0x2e0', '0x22f0', '0x25f0', '0x4800', '0x6500', '0x6c00', '0x6c00', '0x6f00', '0x2c00', '0x2000', '0x5700', '0x6f00', '0x7200', '0x6c00', '0x6400', '0x0']
```

Comment: "I can upload the binary file somewhere if needed." Don't do that. Instead, include a small amount of data (say 32 or 64 bytes) in the question. And also the numbers you want to get from that data. One could say a [mre].

Comment: I edited my question with the needed information.

Comment: Well, now I'm more confused than before. I have no idea if your file is a text file that looks like that, or if that's just a visual representation of your binary data or what. And I don't understand how you get `0x3000`, `0xE005`, `0x2212`, etc from that. If possible, include the data as a python data type - `bytes` or `str` or whatever is suitable.

Comment: So binary `00110000 00000000` equals hex `0x3000`, so far so good. But then it stops making sense. `11100000 00000010` equals `0xE002`, not `0xE005`. And `11110000 00100010` is `0xF022`, so where did the `0x2212` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a different [byte ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) (note 'h' is the format specifier for 16bit ints).

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('h', b'\x30\x00') # default byte ordering
(48,)
>>> struct.unpack('h', b'\x00\x30') # you get the right result if you swap the bytes in the file
(12288,)
>>> struct.unpack('<h', b'\x30\x00') # little endian
(48,)
>>> struct.unpack('>h', b'\x30\x00') # big endian <- this is likely what you want
(12288,)
```

In numpy you can use something like

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.dtype('>h')
dtype('>i2')
```